# Can not make Typo3 Fluid page templating work

Tags: php, fluid, typo3-6.1.x, fedext

I'm trying to start working with the Typo3 Fluid templating engine, and I managed to get it running sort of the dirty way. But then I found the [fedext.net project](http://fedext.net/) together with [this demo](http://bootstrap.typo3cms.demo.typo3.org/). And tried following [this tutorial](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/fluidpages). I end with the following directory structure:

```
typo3conf/
  ext/
    my_extension/
      Classes/
        Controller/
          PageController.php
      Configuration/
        constants.txt <empty for now>
        setup.txt
      Resources/
        Private/
          Layouts/
          Partials/
          Templates/
            Page/
              FrontPage.html
        Public/
      ext_autoload.php <empty>
      ext_emload.php
      ext_localconf.php <empty>
      ext_tables.php
```

**PageController.php:**

```
<?php
class Tx_MyExtension_Controller_PageController extends Tx_Fluidpages_Controller_AbstractPageController {

    public function frontPageAction() {
    }
}
```

**setup.txt:**

```
plugin.tx_myextension.view {
    templateRootPath = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Templates/
    partialRootPath = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Partials/
    layoutRootPath = EXT:my_extension/Resources/Private/Layouts/
}
```

**FrontPage.html:**

```
{namespace v=Tx_Vhs_ViewHelpers}
{namespace flux=Tx_Flux_ViewHelpers}
<f:layout name="Page" />
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"
     xmlns:v="http://fedext.net/ns/vhs/ViewHelpers"
     xmlns:flux="http://fedext.net/ns/flux/ViewHelpers"
     xmlns:f="http://fedext.net/ns/fluid/ViewHelpers">

    <f:section name="Configuration">
        <flux:flexform id="default-page" label="Default page template">
            <flux:flexform.field.input name="settings.entryLevel"
                                       label="Main menu entry level override for this page only"
                                       eval="int,trim" minimum="0" maximum="6"
                                       default="{v:var.typoscript(path: 'lib.menu.main.entryLevel')}">
                <flux:flexform.field.wizard.slider hideParent="TRUE" step="1" width="100" />
            </flux:flexform.field.input>
        </flux:flexform>
        <flux:flexform.grid>
            <flux:flexform.grid.row>
                <flux:flexform.grid.column colPos="1" name="Hero Unit" />
            </flux:flexform.grid.row>
            <flux:flexform.grid.row>
                <flux:flexform.grid.column colPos="0" name="Main Content" />
            </flux:flexform.grid.row>
            <flux:flexform.grid.row>
                <flux:flexform.grid.column colPos="2" name="Footer Content" />
            </flux:flexform.grid.row>
        </flux:flexform.grid>
    </f:section>

    <f:section name="Content">
        <v:page.content.render column="0" />
    </f:section>

    <f:section name="AnotherSection">
        <!-- more sections as desired, rendering triggered from the "Page.html" Layout file -->
    </f:section>

</div>
```

**ext_emconf.php**

```
<?php

$EM_CONF[$_EXTKEY] = array (
    'title' => 'Homepage',
    'description' => 'Homepage',
    'category' => 'misc',
    'shy' => 0,
    'version' => '1.0.0',
    'dependencies' => '',
    'conflicts' => '',
    'priority' => '',
    'loadOrder' => '',
    'module' => '',
    'state' => 'stable',
    'uploadfolder' => 0,
    'createDirs' => '',
    'modify_tables' => '',
    'clearcacheonload' => 0,
    'lockType' => '',
    'author' => 'me',
    'author_email' => 'mail@me.com',
    'author_company' => 'me',
    'CGLcompliance' => NULL,
    'CGLcompliance_note' => NULL,
    'constraints' => 
    array (
        'depends' => 
        array (
            'typo3' => '6.1.0',
            'cms' => '',
            'flux' => '5.0.0',
        ),
        'conflicts' => 
        array (
            'templavoila' => '',
        ),
        'suggests' => 
        array (
        ),
    ),
);

?>
```

**ext_tables.php**

```
<?php
if (!defined ('TYPO3_MODE')) {
    die ('Access denied.');
}

t3lib_extMgm::addStaticFile($_EXTKEY, 'Configuration/TypoScript', 'My Extension Homepage');
Tx_Flux_Core::registerProviderExtensionKey('my_extension', 'Page');
```

**SO, THE PROBLEM IS:** 
Though the backend seems to work, I'm constantly getting PHP fatal-error in the front-end:

> Core: Error handler (FE): PHP Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\apache\htdocs\typo-fluid\typo3temp\Cache\Code\cache_core\ClassLoader_AbstractConfigurationProvider_bc71b4377996b2e6d72f.php line 481

While debugging I found out that the supplied value is null. Looks like I'm missing something simple. But the file structure above is just slightly modified version of [this thing](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/fluidpages_bootstrap)

Is there any good step-by-step tutorial how to create a couple of templates and content elements with *fedext* tools? Because I installed introduction package and tried copying settings in the backend and file structure, but looks like it is not enough and I'm missing something really basic here.

UPDATE:
 I've also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741866/what-is-fluid-powered-typo3-and-is-it-recommended) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15156751/typo3-v6-how-to-create-a-content-element-container-without-tv/15370609#15370609), and hope to get an answer from [Claus Due](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2162619/claus-due) as he is the author of *fedext* tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, looks like the main issue here was not the warning mentioned in the original question, but the error in the **Apache** log:

```
PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Tx_Vhs_Service_AssetService in...
```

which was caused by the [PHP 5.3.3 incompatibility](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/vhs/issues/212) with the **vhs** extension.
So, I've updated the PHP installation and fixed couple of typos in my extension configs, after that it started working as expected.

Comment: Hi Anton, thanks for updating! You are completely right: updating PHP is the only way to avoid these multiple inclusions (which can happen in TYPO3 when the class is referenced first as an EXT:extkey/file.php inclusion and afterwards requested through the object manager). Cheers, Claus.